# How to open xlam which programmed to close when workbook open event

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a VBA Add-In which install itself as `Add-In` by `Addins.Installed` property. But unknowingly I added `ThisWorkBook.Close` after referred [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350305/programatically-install-add-in-vba). Now whenever I open this `xlam` file it opens and closes immediately. I have `MS Excel 2016`. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Set macros security to high, disabling all macros? And open using File/Open. Then remove the close code.

Comment: Disable all macros in the trust center and then open it.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't work

Comment: Did you also disable all add-ins?

Comment: Have you tried opening from another application, say Access, like this?  `Set x = New Excel.Application: x.EnableEvents = False: x.Workbooks.Open ("AddIn.xlam"): x.Visible = True`

Comment: Have to install Access. Will try now.

Comment: or word VBA any office app where you can load excels vba library

Comment: Thank you for vacip, Rory, Nathan_Sav. You are all gave superior suggestions. I resolved it in a dirty way by removing (uncheck) from Add-ins list, move add-in to somewhere, Close and Open Add-ins list and delete from list, again install it manually by Browse even though it does not seem best way.

Comment: As an extra to @vacip - save the current security setting in a `long` variable:  `CurSetting = Application.AutomationSecurity`, change the setting: `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`, open your workbook and then `Application.AutomationSecurity = CurSetting`